# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

> mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/u707958028/public_html/Couponn App/db1.php on line 7
>
> This is my db1.php

```
<?php 
 $database = "blabla"; 
 $server = "blabla";
 $db_user = "blabla";  
 $db_pass = "blabla";
 $link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
 mysqli_select_db($database,$link);
?>
```

Comment: blabla is the name of my hosting site

Comment: try with `localhost` and if remote connection try with full address not just hosting name and may b port also matter

Comment: The error for `musql` & your code has `mysqli`!!

Comment: you can omit the function mysqli_select_db because your can write queries like this `SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename` this also makes it possible to do cross databases table joins

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysqli_select_db` in a wrong way. The first parameter must be the link, and second one must be the name of your database. So:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $database);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extention to Ahmad's answer, using mysqli_select_db is unnecessary as the mysqli_connect function allows you to define the database as an additional parameter.

```
<?php

mysqli_connect("server","username","password","database");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code..

```
`<?php`  
 $database = "blabla";       
 $server = "blabla";      
 $db_user = "blabla";     
 $db_pass = "blabla";     
 $link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);    
 mysqli_select_db($link,$database);      
?>
```

in `mysqli_select_db` first parameter must be database resource link and second argument must be database name.